# Can't detect button click in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I made a small UWP app which is meant to speak "Hello world!" when a button is clicked. But when I ran it I got these errors:

'MainPage does not contain a definition for 'Button_CL' and no accessible extension method 'Button_CL' accepting a first argument of type 'MainPage' could be found (are you <app_name> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) two times and this error too:

The 'CompileXaml' task returned false but did not log an error.

Here is my code:

MainPage.xaml.cs:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/Lu7MU/hgdfjgdhfgkjldfhkjgfhosiudoasi

MainPage.xaml:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/kETpA/gdnlkgjdflgkjdslfkjsfdsgjdsopjgpdfs

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The event method is differently named ("Button_Click" vs. "Button_CL"), they must match in XAML and code-behind.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can run my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declared event in XAML doesn't match the method you implemented in code-behind:

In XAML you have

```
Click="Button_CL"
```

while your C# code has the signature

```
Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

The names must be the same.